# Ordinal Logistic Regression SPSS Interpretation

Tags: regression, spss, odds-ratio, ordered-logit

I have data from a questionnaire study structured like so:

- Age - Ordinal (18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55+)
- Gender - Nominal (Male, Female)
- AnxietyType - Nominal (Self-diagnosed, Professionally diagnosed)
- AnxietyYears - Scale
- ChronicPain - Nominal (No, Yes)
- Response - Ordinal (Strongly Agree, Agree, Neutral, Disagree, Strongly disagree)

I am using SPSS to run an ordinal logistic regression with 'response' as my dependent variable and the other 5 as my independent variables.

When putting the data into SPSS I have coded it as follows:

- Age - (18-24, 0) (25-34, 1) (35-44, 2) (45-54, 3) (55+, 4)
- Gender - (Male, 0) (Female, 1)
- AnxietyType - (Self-diagnosed, 0) (Professionally diagnosed, 1)
- AnxietyYears - Scale
- ChronicPain - (No, 0) (Yes, 1)
- Response - (Strongly Agree, 1) (Agree, 2) (Neutral, 3) (Disagree, 4) (Strongly disagree, 5)

When I run the regression, this is my output with a significant result highlighted in yellow.

[image]

From what I've read and understood about interpreting the results of an ordinal logistic regression, this is saying that:

"The odds ratio of being in a higher category of the dependent variable for males versus females is 2.244" which is saying that males are more likely to agree more strongly than females.

However, when I create a graph looking at the split of responses between males and females it shows that females are actually more likely to agree more strongly than males.
[image]

I would be grateful if anyone could help me to understand what I'm doing wrong - either in my modelling or my interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are just interpreting the response variable in the opposite direction than it should be.

""The odds ratio of being in a higher category of the dependent variable for males versus females is 2.244" which is saying that males are more likely to agree more strongly than females. "

It should be interpreted that males are actually more likely to **disagree** more strongly compared to females.

Because your response variable is coded from 1-5 with strongly agree at the low end and strongly disagree at the high end, an increased likelihood of having a higher category corresponds to an increased likelihood of **disagreeing**. Therefore your plot shows the correct output.

You can reverse the coding of the response variable to get the opposite interpretation (although your estimates will change).